# How to scale a container keeping its bottom right corner fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a red container which initially is at bottom right of black container. I have a scale function that gradually scales the container. I want to make the bottom right position of red container to be fixed and scale it towards top left. How can I do that?

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box")

const initHeight = 200
const initWidth = 200

const centerX = initWidth / 2
const centerY = initHeight / 2

function transform(scale, translate) {
  if (translate) {
    translate[0] = -centerX + translate[0]
    translate[1] = -centerY + translate[1]
  }

  box.style.transform = `scale(${scale})${
    translate ? ` translate(${translate.map((x) => x + "px").toString()})` : ""
  }`
}

let initX = initWidth
let initY = initHeight
let scaleVal = 0.5

transform(scaleVal, [initX, initY])

function scale() {
  scaleVal = scaleVal + 0.01
  transform(scaleVal, [
    initX - scaleVal * initWidth,
    initY - scaleVal * initHeight
  ])
  if (scaleVal <= 1) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      requestAnimationFrame(scale)
    }, 50)
  }
}

scale()
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box" id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't want the red box to move at all but to expand up towards the top left corner of the black box and then shrink back down to its initial size, with the bottom right corner being fixed?

Comment: Exactly @AHaworth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally figured it out,

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box")
let scale = 0

const initWidth = 50
const initHeight = 50

function fixed(num, fix = 1) {
  return Number(parseFloat(num).toFixed(fix))
}

function scaleBox() {
  const [x, y] = [
    fixed((initWidth - scale * initWidth) / 2),
    fixed((initHeight - scale * initHeight) / 2)
  ]

  box.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px) scale(${scale})`
  scale = scale + 0.1

  if (scale < 1) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      requestAnimationFrame(scaleBox)
    }, 500)
  }
}

scaleBox()
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate(0, 0) scale(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box" id="box"></div>
</div>
```

**Explanation**

The trick is to translate the container in such a way that when its scaled after the translation, it always places itself in the bottom right of purple container.

To figure out the translation amount, let's first scale the container to 0.5 without any translation. It looks like this,

[image]

As you can see the container's width is 25 as `0.5(scale) * 50(init_width)=25` and position from container from all sides(top left, bottom left, top right, bottom right) will be `(25/2, 25/2)=(12.5,12.5)` since the container is scaled equally from all sides.

Since the position from bottom right is `(12.5,12.5)`, we need to translate the container to (+12.5,+12.5) and then scale it to exactly place it at bottom right.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To lock the bottom right corner of the red box to the bottom right of the black box this snippet does two things: positions red box right bottom relative to the parent app container and sets the transform-origin to that spot too (normally transform origin is at the center of an element). It then uses a CSS animation to expand the red box and contract it again using scale.

This method does not need JS as it is a simple scaling transform, but of course some of the subtleties of the original transformations are lost because of tying the corner down.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#app {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.box:nth-child(1) {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  animation: scale 5s 1 ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box" id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I don't want to use transform-origin at all. I want to do with the origin being in center.

Comment: Have to say I am lost! It wasn't a condition in the question. Glad you found a solution though.

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear. But hey thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve many things using `display:flex`, it's great!

This is how I would approach your problem:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  const blackDiv = document.getElementById("black-div");
  const redDiv = document.getElementById("red-div");

  let widthRatio = 0;
  let heightRatio = 0;

  const scaleUpTimer = setInterval(() => {
    if (widthRatio === 1 || heightRatio === 1) clearInterval(scaleUpTimer);

    widthRatio = redDiv.offsetWidth / blackDiv.offsetWidth;
    heightRatio = redDiv.offsetHeight / blackDiv.offsetHeight;
    redDiv.style.width = widthRatio * 100 + 2 + "%";
    redDiv.style.height = heightRatio * 100 + 2 + "%";

  }, 10);
};
```

```css
#black-div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#red-div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id='black-div'>
  <div id='red-div' onclick={handleClick()}></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I used onclick here but obviously you would have to handle the situations where someone clicks the red square and its already scaled up to avoid setting unnecessary timers. Or you could just call the function directly, without having to click anything.